# Creating A Function To Check Whether There Is Adjacent Equal Elements In A 2D Array in C

Tags: c

I'm required to create a code that takes a 2D array and then sends it into another function that checks if there is adjacent equal elements by row or by column or by or by diagnoal line and counts them , the search area of each element is narrowed to 1 , so each element checks the 8 elements squaring it and nothing beyond that  , anyone got an idea on how to do it ? i tried adding some if condition but nothing seemed to be working and the counter kept on 0
p.s i left the if() empty because i tried a lot of conditions and none worked
this is what i came up with so far :

````
  #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#define rows 2
#define columns 3
int MatrixCheck(int Matrix[rows][columns])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int Counter = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            if ()
            {
                Counter++;
            }
        }

    }
    return Counter;
}
int Matrix()
{
    int Matrix[rows][columns];
    int i, j, Count = 0, Sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            printf("Enter Value For Place : [%d][%d]   ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &Matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("Matrix Display:  \n");
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            Count++;
            printf("%d   ", Matrix[i][j]);
            if (Count % columns == 0)
            {
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    Matrix();
    MatrixCheck(Matrix);
    printf("Neighbores Count is %d .\n", MatrixCheck(Matrix));
    return 0;
}
    ```
````

Comment: You can check 8 neighbors EXCEPT where `row == 0` or `col == 0` or `col == cols - 1` or `row == rows - 1`. In those special cases you can only check the neighbors that are within the array (not outside it). For the diagonal, the same limit applies, but you only check when `i == j`.

Comment: Try [this](https://pastebin.com/xdLRagTS) method. You need to call it instead of your if, it returns count for equal cells for specified cell.

Comment: Are you wrapping around, cutting off, extending, zeroing, _etc_ your edges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are still stuck, as mentioned in the comment above, what you want to do is loop over each row and column and check the available neighbors for equality. The difficulty is limiting your search of all 8-neighbors when the current index is on an edge or at a corner. For example is your 2D arrays has dimensions of `ROWS x COLS`, and you loop:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
```

You are on the top and bottom edge at `i == 0` and `i == ROWS-1`, and on the left and right edge at `j == 0` and `j == COLS-1`. You are in the top corners at `[0][0]`, `[0][COLS-1]` and bottom corners at `[ROWS-1][0]`, `[ROWS-1][COLS-1]`.

There are two ways to approach limiting the checks of surrounding neighbors to ensure you do not check elements outside your array bounds. You can just loop over `i` and `j` above and create a rather lengthy set of `if ... else if ... else if ... else` statements covering the cases on each edge and corner. Essentially avoiding using further nested loops by unrolling the logic you would need to capture in setting the nested loop limits. There are likely performance advantages to this approach, but the length of the code needed may be 4 - 8 times what is needed with nested loop.

With nested loops you would need to loop:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            /* loop from i-1 to i+1 */
                /* loop from j-1 to j+1 */
```

This produces much shorter code, but takes a bit of care in how you set the limits for each of the last two loops. If you are not familiar with a *ternary*, it is essentially a shorthand `if ... else ...` that can be used inline. The basic format is `(condition) ? if_true : if_false`. So with the inner loops above you can limit the range for each of loops from `i` to `i+1` if `i == 0` and from `i-1` to `i` if `i == ROWS-1` (and similarly for the inner loop over columns)

You also need an additional condition to avoid checking whether the current index is equal to itself to create a valid neighbors count. So with the original elements in `arr` and then number of neighbors for each index captured in `sum`, you could do something similar to the following:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {        /* loop over each row */
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {    /* loop over each col */
            /* loop k from i-1 to i+1, use ternary to omit out of bounds checks */
            for (int k = i ? i-1 : i; k <= ((i < ROWS - 1) ? i + 1 : i); k++) {
                /* loop l from j-1 to j+1, user ternary to omit out of bounds checks */
                for (int l = j ? j-1 : j; l <= ((j < COLS - 1) ? j + 1 : j); l++) {
                    /* if not comparing element to itself */
                    if (arr[i][j] == arr[k][l] && !(k == i && j == l))
                        sum[i][j] += 1;     /* increment sum[i][j] */
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

(**note:** a *ternary* is used both to initialize the loop count and to set the loop limit for each of the loops)

A full example that generates a 10x10 array with random values of `1-10` outputs the array, and then checks neighbors with the logic above and then outputs the results in **Minesweeper format** for lack of better words where each cell contains the count of the number of equivalent neighbors surrounding it, outputting an empty sell if there are no equal neighbors, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ROWS 10         /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define COLS ROWS       /* 10 x 10 */

int main (void) {
    
    int arr[ROWS][COLS] = {{0}},        /* array holding random values 1-10 */
        sum[ROWS][COLS] = {{0}};        /* array holding no. surrounding elements equal */
    
    srand (time(NULL));                 /* seed random number generator */
    
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {                /* loop filling array/output */
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 10 + 1;
            printf (j ? " %3d" : "%3d", arr[i][j]);
        }
        putchar ('\n');
    }
    putchar ('\n');
    
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {        /* loop over each row */
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {    /* loop over each col */
            /* loop k from i-1 to i+1, use ternary to omit out of bounds checks */
            for (int k = i ? i-1 : i; k <= ((i < ROWS - 1) ? i + 1 : i); k++) {
                /* loop l from j-1 to j+1, user ternary to omit out of bounds checks */
                for (int l = j ? j-1 : j; l <= ((j < COLS - 1) ? j + 1 : j); l++) {
                    /* if not comparing element to itself */
                    if (arr[i][j] == arr[k][l] && !(k == i && j == l))
                        sum[i][j] += 1;     /* increment sum[i][j] */
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    puts ("\nNumber Surrounding Cells Equal (minesweeper format):\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            if (sum[i][j])
                printf ("  %d ", sum[i][j]);    /* if >= 1 output */
            else
                fputs ("    ", stdout);         /* otherwise output blank cell */
        putchar ('\n');
    }
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/arr_edges_adj_equal
  6   9   7  10   3  10  10   8   9   6
  9   9   4   1   4  10   5   9   6  10
  5   5   7   6   2   8   1   6   3  10
  2  10   8  10   1   1   9  10  10  10
  6  10  10   1  10   6   2   4   4   8
  3   9   2   2   6   5   9   6   2   3
  5   6   4   3   5   4   3   6   3   2
  7  10   1   6   3   3   1   4   6   7
  1   1   5   5   2  10   1   2   7   5
  6   2  10   9   4   4   4   8   1   6


Number Surrounding Cells Equal (minesweeper format):

      2               2   2       1   1
  2   2               2       1   2   1
  1   1                   1   1       3
      2       2   2   2       1   3   2
      2   3   1   1   1       1   1
          1   1   1   1       1   1   1
              1   1       1   2   1   1
          1       2   2   1       1   1
  1   2   1   1           1       1
                  1   2   1
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.